# tar :cannot stat : No such file or directory when shell script run

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am hoping that more experts here will find some obvious syntax error or will be able to help me work around the errors.

**Basic idea of the script:**
I have a shell script which will read the list.txt and look for the files or folders I need, then copy to another directory.

**Working Environment:**
Ubuntu 12.04

**Problem/Error:**
Before I modify, I have a demo script which copy all the files that works fine.  However, when I modify the script, it gives me this error : 
*tar : XXXXX.ko cannot stat : No such file or directory
tar : Exiting with failure status due to previous errors*

The only thing I change is the path of the list.

**Shell script code shown as below**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/leo/Desktop/Script_testing
INSTALL_PATH=./output/.install/
NAND2_PATH=./output/nand1-2_2
if [ ! -d $NAND2_PATH ]; then
mkdir $NAND2_PATH
fi
if [ ! -f /home/leo/Desktop/Script_testing/list2.txt ]; then
echo "error : list_2 not found : "
exit
fi
cd $INSTALL_PATH
tar cf - `cat /home/leo/Desktop/Script_testing/list2.txt` | ( cd ../../../${NAND2_PATH} ; tar xf - )
```

**And here is my list2.txt :**

```
./app_drvier/led/led.ko
./Desktop/testing/beeper.h
./Desktop/testing/beeper.c
./bin/usb_plug.sh
./etc/hostname
```

when I run `./mycp.sh` the directory "nand1-2_2: will be created under output, however, the error I have mentioned shown
`tar : XXXXX cannot stat : No such file or directory
tar : Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Hope someone can help me out. Thank you so much

**Update**
After I run `sh -x mycp.sh`, result as below

```
+ cd /home/dragon/Desktop/Script_testing
+ INSTALL_PATH=./output/.install/
+ NAND2_PATH=./output/nand1-2_2
+ [ ! -d ./output/nand1-2_2 ]
+ [ ! -f /home/dragon/Desktop/Script_testing/list2.txt ]
+ cd ./output/.install/
nand1-2_2.sh: 12: cd: can't cd to ./output/.install/
+ cd ../../.././output/nand1-2_2
nand1-2_2.sh: 13: cd: can't cd to ../../.././output/nand1-2_2
+ tar xf -
+ cat /home/dragon/Desktop/Script_testing/list2.txt
+ tar cf - ./app_drvier/ontech_led/onetech.led.ko
tar: ./app_drvier/ontech_led/onetech.led.ko: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: The basic debug is to use the `-x` bash option. Run `sh -x mycp.sh` and pay attention on the output.

Comment: @Jdamian I just tried this and I have the print-out posted there.  Please have a look when you have time

Comment: Can you not see the errors shown there? They are meaningful -- The `INSTALL_PATH` does not exist or you have not access (permission issue). Thus, the `cd` commands cannot work.

Comment: Does the file  ./app_drvier/led/led.ko exist in this path ? As @Jdamian said, the error is self explanatory.

Comment: @MayurNagekar It exists

Comment: Get your directories right. Both `cd` fail.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the file ./app_drvier/ontech_led/onetech.led.ko does not exist. This is not a surprise, because both cd commands executed earlier, fail.

The root cause seems to be, that the directory ./output/.install either does not exist or that you don't have permission to chdir into it.

I suggest that you always evaluate the exit status of the cd commands. If the cd fails, it doesn't make sense to continue the script running.

For instance, you could write:

```
cd $INSTALL_PATH || exit 1
```

Comment: Or `set -e` for the lazy.